# How to change only one ion-item color in ion-list when clicked?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have tried multiple things but I can't seem to figure this one out.
I have an **ion-list** with multiple **ion-items** that I get from an array with the help of ***ngFor**. When I click on one item, I only want its' color to be changed. I've managed to be able to change all the ion-item colors when I click one of them but **that's not what I want.**

This is a code snippet:

```
      <ion-col>
         <ion-item *ngFor="let exercise of exercisesArray" (click)="onClick(exercise)"  [ngStyle]="{color: color}"> 
          {{exercise.title}}
        </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-list>
```

As you can see, I tried changing the color variable when clicking in the function onClick(exercise). I need the exercise as a parameter for other purposes. Anyways, that works but all the items in the exerciseArray get that color.
But as I said, I would like to only change the color of the item that has been clicked.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Do you just want to keep showing it as Selected Item and change the color when user click another item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a Variable and check index of your `*ngFor`if item gets clicked change color.

.ts

```
selectedItem: any;
```

.html

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let exercise of exercisesArray; let i = index" (click)="onClick(exercise); selectedItem = i"  [ngStyle]="{color: selectedItem == i ? YourNewColor : null}">
{{exercise.title}}
</ion-item>
```

update you `selectedItem` variable when Item gets clicked and check it in your `ngStyle` to apply new Color.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that, create the `exercisesArray` like this for example -

```
exercisesArray = [
    {
      title: "A",
      color: "green"
    },
    {
      title: "B",
      color: "green"
    },
    {
      title: "C",
      color: "green"
    }
  ];
```

and in onclick function, send the id of the array that has been clicked and based on that id, change the color of that object. for example,

```
this.exercisesArray[index].color = 'red';
```

For further reference, take a look at [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-sunset-ufcuz?file=/src/app/app.component.ts:215-229)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't really get what you mean by setting an object of each item "as key" or I don't really know how to do that. May you explain that please?